# I'm trying to compile Bitcoin Gold but i'm still getting this error

Tags: compiling, bitcoin-gold, c++

```
In file included from ./addrman.h:14:0,
                 from net.h:10,
                 from miner.cpp:18:
miner.cpp: In member function ‘std::unique_ptr BlockAssembler::CreateNewBlock(const CScript&, bool)’:
miner.cpp:197:67: error: too many arguments to function ‘int64_t GetBlockWeight(const CBlock&)’
 nSerializeSize, GetBlockWeight(*pblock, chainparams.GetConsensus()), nBlockTx, nFees, nBlockSigOpsCost);
                                                                   ^
./util.h:148:33: note: in definition of macro ‘LogPrintf’
         _log_msg_ = tfm::format(__VA_ARGS__); \
                                 ^
In file included from miner.cpp:15:0:
consensus/validation.h:100:23: note: declared here
 static inline int64_t GetBlockWeight(const CBlock& block)
                       ^
In file included from ./addrman.h:14:0,
                 from net.h:10,
                 from miner.cpp:18:
miner.cpp:197:67: error: too many arguments to function ‘int64_t GetBlockWeight(const CBlock&)’
 nSerializeSize, GetBlockWeight(*pblock, chainparams.GetConsensus()), nBlockTx, nFees, nBlockSigOpsCost);
                                                                   ^
./util.h:151:125: note: in definition of macro ‘LogPrintf’
         _log_msg_ = "Error \"" + std::string(fmterr.what()) + "\" while formatting log message: " + FormatStringFromLogArgs(__VA_ARGS__); \
                                                                                                                             ^
In file included from miner.cpp:15:0:
consensus/validation.h:100:23: note: declared here
 static inline int64_t GetBlockWeight(const CBlock& block)
                       ^
```

Comment: I really need help